# Negative number modulo in R

Tags: r, math, division, modulo, negative-number

For -2%%5 and -2%%7. The remainder is 3 and 5. I tried to see how they arrived at 3 and 5 with

`a == (a/b)*b + a%b`

but I still don't have 3 and 5. How does a negative number works in modulo in R?

Answer (score 1):

R is consistent with a "floored division" approach.
Consider also where your divisor is negative e.g. `2 %% -7`.

In your case, it makes sense like this:

```
a <- -2
b <- 5

(a %/% b) * b + a %% b #== a
#> [1] -2 

all.equal(a,  (a %/% b) * b + a %% b)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Here `%/%` is floored division and `%%` is the remainder in this respect. I.e.

```
quotient <- floor(a/b)  # = a %/% b
remainder <- a - b*q    # = a %% b
a == quotient*b + remainder
#> [1] TRUE
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) has a pretty good discussion about it.